# How would I remove this brush

Tags: untagged

[image]

What would be the easiest method to remove all of this dead weeds and grass ?

Comment: Easiest? Hire someone else to get rid of it...

Comment: Can you add more details...such as is there leaf and yard waste pickup where you live, do you have a compost pile...   Please edit your question, add more details and we will reopen

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close to the building to be doing burning. It would not be my choice.

If there is an out-of-sight place on your land you can start yourself a mulch pile. Get your wheelbarrow. Get your garden shears. Pull on a chunk. Cut with the shears to give yourself manageable chunks that will fit in the wheelbarrow. Load up the wheelbarrow and take it to the mulch pile. Once there just tip on the pile.

If a mulch pile is not on, you will need to bag and dispose. Your local city rules will tell you when and how you can dispose of yard waste. Maybe you must use special bags and put them out on particular days. Use the garden shears to cut the larger bits. That way you can get more in a bag. If the stuff pulls up easily, bang off any soil clinging on. If it does not pull up easily, just cut it off at the ground and leave the dead roots. You should be able to break them up with your spade. You should be able to get all this pile in one big bag, two at most.

You *might* try attacking with a "weed whacker." That will mean you get a bunch of small bits. This has the disadvantage that this debris is now in small bits over the area. But, depending on exactly what's in there, this might rot away fairly quickly. Much like fallen leaves do. Or you could try raking up the small bits.  Maybe try that with a small portion of the pile and try to judge what is the easier method.

Comment: Note that brush piles usually attract rabbits and sometimes voles. The rabbits seem to rely on them for housing in winter in snowy areas, then make their burrows nearby in the spring.